# Terraform Exception Handling with Route53 Resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, devops, infrastructure-as-code

I've got a problem working with aws resources via terraform. In my case, Route53 returns an error shown as below

```
data "aws_route53_zone" "zone" {
  name         = "example.com."
  private_zone = false
}
```

After these data source giving an error, shown as below

> no matching Route53Zone found

I want to handle these exception an if a record not found in route53 create a record in Route53. To summarize I want to handle exceptions as conditionals.

Comment: Your data source is looking for a Route53 _zone_ not a record. And is there a reason you can't just create the record with the `aws_route53_record`? Unfortunately the API for R53 RecordSets means that create/updates use the same API call so if the record exists then it will simply be overwritten rather than fail like other resources that are identified by a user provided ID such as a name.

Comment: As mentioned above, the data source cannot be used to look for a record , you can try to create the record if exists then terraform will skip it or update if there is a diff with the new one

Comment: Are those route53 records already in terraform or do you want to backport them from aws into terraform and then manage them? If that's your end goal then it's probably better to do that rather than trying to apply conditional logic. Terraform doesn't have the functionality you're looking for FYI but you really wanted this you could use a local exec to run the awscli to grep for whatever record and then if that record existed check for the value of that record as a conditional count but that's quite a rube goldberg machine...